# Authenticating with Exchange Web Services from server after setting up impersonation context

Tags: c#, asp.net, kerberos, exchangewebservices

I have the following setup for an app I want to use on the local network:

```
Silverlight Client App -> Web Server (data objects etc) | -> Exchange
                                                        | -> SQL Database
```

Everything else works fine, I can get data from the DB, etc (might be worth noting I'm using SQL auth for SQL not windows auth), but when I try to get calendar entries for the current user from exchange using Exchange Web Services it gives me a `401 unauthorised` error.

This is all running on my local dev server (on my machine) which is running under a classic ASP.NET 4 app pool using the default ApplicationPoolIdentity. I'm not coming in via SSL, just over port 81

I can connect to get **my own** calendar entries, *but for **other** users I get the error*

If I try it without the impersonation code, I get a `Connection did not succeed. Please try again later` error since I assume that EWS will be using ApplicationPoolIdentity which doesn't have a domain logon.

I've used the following code to impersonate (ignore any potentially unhandled exceptions/security holes for now I just want to get it working!):

```
var impersonationContext = ((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity).Impersonate();

// Use default credentials
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

// Get the target folder ID using the email address
var folder = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox(emailAddress));

// Get the appointments
var response = service.FindAppointments(folder, view);

impersonationContext.Undo();


// Return list of appointment entities
return response.Items;
```

Looking at `System.Security.Principal.GetCurrent()` shows that the user changes to the identity of the user I want to impersonate after the `Impersonate` method is called. The AuthenticationType is `Kerberos` and the `ImpersonationLevel` is `Impersonate`. As far as I can see this should work but it looks like my web server doesn't want to successfully auth with exchange.

Am I missing something in my setup or in exchange?

Comment: AFAIK because of the "server hop" this will only work if you have Kerberos delegation enabled for your servers.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This ended up working in the end - it ended up being some exchange settings and using the current threads principal instead of the system principal

Comment: What exchange settings? Having the same issue.

Comment: Well that's the problem - I have no idea :) at the time the CTO wouldn't let me near the servers - it was a case of "try now...... try now.... try now...", sorry :(